# Puppeteer Button Press

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

According to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepresskey-options, you can simulate the pressing of a keyboard button with Puppeteer.

Here's what I do:

```
// First, click the search button
await page.click('#outer-container > nav > span.right > span.search-notification-wrapper > span > form > input[type="text"]');
// Focus on the input field
await page.focus('#outer-container > nav > span.right > span.search-notification-wrapper > span > form > input[type="text"]');
// Enter some text into the input field
await page.type("Bla Bla");
// Press Enter to search -> this doesn't work!
await page.press("Enter");
```

The pressing of the button doesn't produce anything. It's basically ignored.

How can I simulate the Enter key to submit the form?

Comment: Maybe try to submit the form `const form = await page.$('#outer-container > nav > span.right > span.search-notification-wrapper > span > form');
await form.evaluate(form => form.submit());`

Comment: Will try that, thanks @codtex!

Comment: I've tried. It seems to do something (the result is that the page reloads basically). However, the desired form isn't submitted and I do not see any results.

Comment: Sorry Elena I'm not an expert on puppeteer, event it was my first time to check it's documentation, but what is the purpose of your task - do you want to actually submit the form ? or maybe find and click the submit button ? - there might be a javascript that is performing the search without reloading the page

Comment: @codtex sure, I understand. Well, I am just trying to get results for a search. There's a search input box where you enter the search term. When the Enter button is pressed, it should return the results.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've figured it out finally. I found inside that same form an anchor element whose type was submit. I then clicked on it and the form was submitted.

Here's the code I've used:

```
const form = await page.$('a#topbar-search');
await form.evaluate( form => form.click() );
```

You can also use the $eval method instead of evaluate:

```
await page.$eval( 'a#topbar-search', form => form.click() );
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps another option could be:

```
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
```

Leveraging its virtual keyboard API. More info info [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-keyboard)

Answer (score 10):

```
await page.$eval('input[name=btnK]', el => el.click());
```

this will click the submit button in google. As for your page find out the elements or buttons id and then use it.

Comment: this is bad practice, you should return the element and then in the next line of code click on it using puppeter click function

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own element using xpath.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
const txtObject = await page.$x('.//input[type="text"]');
await txtObject[0].type('bla bla bla');
```

In this above code we use "$x" to retrieve all the elements in one array, thats why we use in "0" as index in the next code line. If you have more than one object you can use a "IF" condition and one loop to search the correct space and use the correct object. Other way if you have a few attributes, you also can use something like that to have a clean and easy way to identify your object

```
await page.click('input[type="submit"]'); // With type
await page.click('input[class="ng-newstyle"]'); //With class attribute
```

And you can reduce the maintenance complexity in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, `page.press()` is **not a valid Puppeteer method**. Using `page.press()` results in the following error:

> Error running your code. TypeError: page.press is not a function

You are likely referring to [`page.keyboard.press()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardpresskey-options).

See below for a comprehensive list on how to emulate the Enter key in Puppeteer:

---

#### page.keyboard.press():

You can use [`page.keyboard.press()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardpresskey-options) to simulate pressing the enter key. Any of the following options should work:

```
await page.keyboard.press('Enter'); // Enter Key
await page.keyboard.press('NumpadEnter'); // Numeric Keypad Enter Key
await page.keyboard.press('\n'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.press('\r'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
```

#### elementHandle.press():

Additionally, you can use use a combination of [`page.$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector) and [`elementHandle.press()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlepresskey-options) to focus on an element before pressing enter:

```
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('Enter'); // Enter Key
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('NumpadEnter'); // Numeric Keypad Enter Key
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('\n'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('\r'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
```

#### page.type():

Furthermore, you can use [`page.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options):

```
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

#### page.keyboard.type():

Likewise, you can use [`page.keyboard.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardtypetext-options):

```
await page.keyboard.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

#### page.keyboard.sendCharacter():

Another alternative method would be to use the [`page.keyboard.sendCharacter()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardsendcharacterchar) method:

```
await page.keyboard.sendCharacter(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

#### page.keyboard.down() / page.keyboard.up():

You can also use a combination of [`page.keyboard.down()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboarddownkey-options) and [`page.keyboard.up()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardupkey):

```
// Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('Enter');
await page.keyboard.up('Enter');

// Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('NumpadEnter');
await page.keyboard.up('NumpadEnter');

// Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('\n');
await page.keyboard.up('\n');

// Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('\r');
await page.keyboard.up('\r');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the below code to `click` acting to the buttons.

```js
const searchButtonNodeSelector = ".submit-button";
await page.click(searchButtonNodeSelector);
```

This API is explained [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageclickselector-options).