# Fetch file to variable via button click in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, fetch, puppeteer

I am aware, that if I know the URL, then I can fetch a file to a variable like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    return fetch(URL, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include"
    }).then(r => r.text());
});
```

My problem is, that there is no direct URL, just a button in the page which does some JS magic and then the download begins.

What code would trigger the download in this case via button click (no form)

**UPDATE**

This code works for download via button click:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
    behavior: 'allow',
    downloadPath: '/home/domain.tld/tmp',
});
await page.click('#exportButton');
await page.waitFor(20000);
```

1. Is there a way to set the filename?
2. How can I do this without downloading the file, but fetch into a variable?

Thanks,

Comment: So you're just trying to emulate a click? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342930/puppeteer-button-press

Comment: And maybe use `Page.setDownloadBehavior` before (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1478)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I can download the file with `Page.setDownloadBehavior` is there a way to set the filename?

Comment: Not sure. Internet seems to say there is no way. Now that your answer is provided, could you care answering you own question with the updated code? For future people :)

Comment: I edited my question. If you write your suggestion as an answer I am more than happy to accept it :)

Comment: Okay I won't post it because your request is actually "INTO a variable", and I don't have the answer for that ;)

Comment: Thanks, then I wait for a bit more :)