# How to login with Puppeteer? Error: No node found for selector: #login-email

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to log in to our company's Runscope tests page. My code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const C = require('./constants');
const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#login-email';
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#login-password';
const CTA_SELECTOR = '#login-submit';

async function startBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return { browser, page };
}

async function closeBrowser(browser) {
    return browser.close();
}

async function playTest(url) {
    const { browser, page } = await startBrowser();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(C.username);
    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(C.password);
    await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
}

(async () => {
    await playTest("https://www.runscope.com/ckapi/mr/36ba13e6-d2pp-477b-8149-2935fa768c29");
    process.exit(1);
})();
```

I got this warning

```
(node:10040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #login-email
    at Object.assert (C:\Users\v-mimaliprc\runscope2\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\assert.js:26:15)
    at DOMWorld.click (C:\Users\v-mimaliprc\runscope2\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:277:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async playTest (C:\Users\v-mimaliprc\runscope2\index.js:21:5)
    at async C:\Users\v-mimaliprc\runscope2\index.js:31:5
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

WHat is wrong with my code? I placed Username and Password into constants file.

Comment: Maybe try `await page.waitForSelector(someSelector)` before clicking on it. I get a 404 on your URL so you might want to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selector is probably not rendered yet. Try to use those lanes before event call:

```js
await page.waitFor(500)
await page.waitForSelector(USERNAME_SELECTOR)
await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
...
```

[Similar solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342930/puppeteer-button-press)